# How to align total fields in column footer?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a report in Jasper iReport. But the alignment of fields in not appropriate as I want.

I have added the Date and SMS Count in `Detail band` and total sms count in `Column band`. When I have total sms count  in `detail band` then it iterate and show multiple time.

Sms Count Report Image:

[image: Sms Count Report Image]

XML code is ...

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="smsCount" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\NIC\\Desktop\\report\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="fromDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="toDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select (select sum(sent_count) from IMMIGRATION.OVERSTAY_SENT_SMS_COUNT  where sent_date between $P{fromDate} and $P{toDate}) totalCount,to_char(sent_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') sent_date,sent_count from IMMIGRATION.OVERSTAY_SENT_SMS_COUNT where sent_date
between $P{fromDate} and $P{toDate}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="TOTALCOUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="SENT_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SENT_COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="83" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="122" y="21" width="420" height="48" forecolor="#FF9999"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="30"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[National Informatic Center]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="234" y="0" width="139" height="24"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="14" isUnderline="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SMS Count Reports]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="61" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="404" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[SMS Count]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="61" y="9" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SENT_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="404" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SENT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="35">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="404" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTALCOUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="291" y="0" width="113" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isItalic="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[     Total SMS Count=]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
```

Comment: Consider to accept the best answer (green check next to answer you prefeer) , see [accepted-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Activate "Float column footer" in report properties.

[image: Ireport Screenshot]

Comment: @AtulRai: Glad to help. If you consider my answer the most helpful, please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

What iReport version did you use?
Try to put the 'total sms count' in another level of footer as page-footer.